# Cannot save empty text box value to database.(format is in int)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When i give empty value to bank region and cost centre it gives the error during saving to database.

Error:input string was not in a correct format.

```
   objMEndorsement.BankRegion =  Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text);
   objMEndorsement.CostCenter = Convert.ToInt32(txtCostCenter.Text);
```

this is the code i used.How i will save empty textbox value to database.

Comment: Empty value cannot be converted into `int`.

Comment: You could store as a nullable int `int?`

Comment: Then how i have to do.

Comment: Check for `empty` or `null` values before trying to convert to `int`. like this - `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBankRegion.Text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
objMEndorsement.BankRegion =  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBankRegion.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `int.TryParse()` this is better in handling conversion.

You can do it this way:

```
int bankRegion = 0; //Default value if wasn't able to parse
int.TryParse( txtBankRegion.Text, out value );
objMEndorsement.BankRegion = bankRegion;
```

Then you can do the same with the other field.

Answer (score 0):

yes use ternary operator and assign corresponding values 
objMEndorsement.BankRegion = (txtBankRegion.Text.trim()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text)

Comment: You really need to provide an example along with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 objMEndorsement.BankRegion =  Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text);
 objMEndorsement.CostCenter = Convert.ToInt32(txtCostCenter.Text);
```

by

```
 objMEndorsement.BankRegion =  Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text??0);
 objMEndorsement.CostCenter = Convert.ToInt32(txtCostCenter.Text??0);
```

?? is null coalesce operator in c#

EDIT:
Best option would be to use tryParse like this

```
bool isInteger=int.TryParse(txtBankRegion.Text??0, out num1);
if(isInteger)
{
//insert into database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make objMEndorsement.BankRegion NULLable and:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBankRegion.Text))
    objMEndorsement.BankRegion =  Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text)
```

(This works if NULL is the initial value of the property objMEndorsement.BankRegion =  Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text))

Otherwise (property still have to accept NULL):

```
objMEndorsement.BankRegion = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBankRegion.Text) ? null : Convert.ToInt32(txtBankRegion.Text);
```

Remember that your database field must be NULLable also (otherwise you will get a DB error when trying to persist NULL).

Answer (score 0):

make it nullable type by converting the value type to nullable type and then send it to database